# Решение задачи. Modular Calculator

Tags: c++

Задача : http://www.codeabbey.com/index/task_view/modular-calculator.
Решение:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned long long int n;
    int n2;
    char c;
    cin >> n;
    cin >> c;
    while (c != '%')
    {
        cin >> n2;

        if (c == '+')
            n += n2;
        else if (c == '*')
            n *= n2;

        cin >> c;
    }
    cin >> n2;

    n %= n2;

    cout << n;
    return 0;
}
```

Сайт говорит, что ответ не верный.

Comment: Ответ получается не верный, т.к. происходит переполнение. К примеру мне попались входные значения которые приводят к числам большим `2,2821327 × 10^38`, тогда как максимальное значение `unsigned long long` - `4 294 967 295`, что, мягко говоря, меньше, чем нужно. Решить задачу вам поможет длинная арифметика.